# Call Recorder in Android 7 doesn't record remote voice

Tags: android

I'm working in Call Recording application in Android to record both sides voice, its work fine in android version up to 6 but not in Android 7.The problem in Android 7 is a remote voice is not recorded or may be not audible.

I'm using MediaRecorder for this.I try all audio sources but no luck.
If anybody knows how to achieve this in Android 7, Please share it or some advice regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question properly, using the [provided markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Get involved in my project https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib Let's find a solution together!

Comment: You can refer this answer, This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53799568/1776625

Answer (score 0):

For Android 7 you should use:

```
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
```

to recording call, althought it is MIC but it records 2 sides of the call.
For the general on all Android versions you can refer this rule:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    callType = "VOICE_CALL";
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    callType = "MIC";
} else {
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
    callType = "VOICE_COMMUNICATION";
}
```

I created my github for demo: https://github.com/tntkhang/call-recording-master