# record call on Android nougat 7.0

Tags: java, android, call, android-7.0-nougat, android-mediarecorder

i am using a simple mediarecorder to record calls
it's work fine on devices < nougat 
but in nougat it record audio of call just my side.. not other side voice 
i try to change audiosource and not working 
is there any way to record other side voice?

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();  
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);  
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);  
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);  
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Check my answer, it's worked for my project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53799568/1776625

Answer (score 0):

After a month research about Call Recording, I found that on each Android version has it appreciate the type of MediaRecorder to make it work, we can not use only one type for all android version. This rule I am using for my project and currently, it's work all most android version.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    callType = "VOICE_CALL";
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    callType = "MIC";
} else {
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
    callType = "VOICE_COMMUNICATION";
}
```

For fast check, you can check my example: https://github.com/tntkhang/call-recording-master